# using Terraform to pass a file to newly created ec2 instance without sharing the private key in "connection" section

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My setup is:
Terraform --> AWS ec2

using Terraform to create the ec2 instance with SSH access.

The

```
resource "aws_instance" "inst1" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  key_name      = "aws_key"
  subnet_id     = ...
  user_data     = file("./deploy/templates/user-data.sh")

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    ... ,
  ]
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./deploy/templates/ec2-caller.sh"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/ec2-caller.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /home/ubuntu/ec2-caller.sh",      
    ]
  }

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = self.public_ip
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("./keys/aws_key_enc")
    timeout     = "4m"
  }
}
```

the above bit works and i could see the provisioner copying and executing the 'ec2-caller.sh.
I don't want to pass my private key in clear text to the Terraform provisioner. Is there anyway we can copy files to the newly created ec2 without using provisioner or without passing the private key on to the provisioner?

Cheers.

Comment: You could upload your file to an S3 bucket and adjust the user data script to download it. With this approach you don't have to use a provisioner.

Comment: You don't need to pass the private key. 

Its the Public key which is copied inside the Ec2 Instance from the Ec2 Key Pair 

Please read about Key-Pair and Pem files in general

Comment: @Ajinkya,                                                                              
`aws_instance.myapp-server: Provisioning with 'file'...
╷
│ Error: file provisioner error
│ 
│   with aws_instance.myapp-server,
│   on main.tf line 140, in resource "aws_instance" "myapp-server":
│  140:   provisioner "file" {
│ 
│ Failed to read ssh private key: no key found
` I get this error if don't provide the private key.

Comment: @ Ervin Szilagyi - Thanks. thats one way around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Terraform documentation section [Provisioners are a Last Resort](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) raises the need to provision and pass in credentials as one of the justifications for provisioners being a "last resort", and then goes on to suggest some other strategies for [passing data into virtual machines and other compute resources](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#passing-data-into-virtual-machines-and-other-compute-resources).

You seem to already be using `user_data` to specify some other script to run, so to follow the advice in that document would require combining these all together into a single [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) configuration. (I'm assuming that your AMI has cloud-init installed because that's what's typically responsible for interpreting `user_data` as a shell script to execute.)

Cloud-init supports [several different `user_data` formats](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html), with the primary one being [cloud-init's own YAML configuration file format, "Cloud Config"](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#cloud-config-data). You can also use a [multipart MIME message](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#mime-multi-part-archive) to pack together multiple different `user_data` payloads into a single `user_data` body, as long as the combined size of the payload fits within EC2's upper limit for `user_data` size, which is 16kiB.

From your configuration it seems like you have two steps you'd need cloud-init to deal with in order to fully solve this problem with cloud-init:

- Run the `./deploy/templates/user-data.sh` script.
- Place the `/home/ubuntu/ec2-caller.sh` on disk with suitable permissions.

Assuming that these two steps are independent of one another, you can send `cloud-init` a multipart MIME message which includes both the user-data script you were originally using alone *and* a Cloud Config YAML configuration to place the `ec2-caller.sh` file on disk. [The Terraform provider `hashicorp/cloudinit`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/cloudinit) has a data source [`cloudinit_config`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/cloudinit/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudinit_config) which knows how to construct multipart MIME messages for cloud-init, which you could use like this:

```
data "cloudinit_config" "example" {
  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = file("${path.root}/deploy/templates/user-data.sh")
  }

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content = yamlencode({
      write_files = [
        {
          encoding    = "b64"
          content     = filebase64("${path.root}/deploy/templates/ec2-caller.sh")
          path        = "/home/ubuntu/ec2-caller.sh"
          owner       = "ubuntu:ubuntu"
          permissions = "0755"
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "inst1" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  key_name      = "aws_key"
  subnet_id     = ...
  user_data     = data.cloudinit_config.example.rendered

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    ... ,
  ]
}
```

The second `part` block above includes YAML based on the cloud-init example *[Writing out arbitrary files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files)*, which you could refer to in order to learn what other settings are possible. [Terraform's `yamlencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/yamlencode) doesn't have a way to generate the special `!!binary` tag used in some of the files in that example, but setting `encoding: b64` allows passing the base64-encoded text as just a normal string.

Comment: Really spoton matee. this worked like charm. awesome, amazing. spinoff is perfect and my script executed very well